# Upload Multiple Files HTML5 / PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I'm trying to build a basic upload form to add multiple files to a folder, which is processed by PHP.

The HTML code I have is:

```
<form id="form" action="add-files-php.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="addSection">Files To Add:<br><input type="file" name="files[]" multiple /></div>
    <div class="addSection"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Files" /></div>
</form>
```

And the PHP to process is:

```
$file_path = "../a/files/article-files/$year/$month/";
foreach ($_FILES['files']['files'] as $file) {    
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"],"$file_path");
}
```

I can run the PHP without any errors, but the files don't get added to the path folder.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar code actually in one of my projects. Try it.

```
foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $file_path);
}
```

Look at the following page:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

EDIT:
Nowhere in the code you provided, does it show that you actually give your file a filename, you simply refer to a path, rather than a path+filename+extension

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $file_path . $name);
```

modifying my original code sample to be like the second one, should work.

Comment: Thanks. I've actually just been looking at a very similar code at http://www.w3bees.com/2013/02/multiple-file-upload-with-php.html, but unfortunately the code that you gave me still isn't uploading the files. What does `$name` relate to in your example?

Comment: The $name is used in my example, to refer to the file when generating error messages... however, I stripped this away from my example. 

it is important that:

Comment: <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />

the name of the input, is the same as the name that is used referring to in $_FILES[]

Comment: Sorry about all these comments. Try for example to print out the variable $_FILES["files"] using print_r to see what happens

Comment: As I see, looking at your example... what is missing, is actually the part where you give the file a file name in the file path... basically you're moving the file to a path without a filename. 

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $file_path . $name);

Comment: Thanks. I've removed $name, but now I'm getting an error `unexpected ')' ` on the `foreach` row!

Comment: when going through a foreach loop you go through foreach(variable as $index > $key) {} (or foreach(variable as key) {} )

don't remove it, try this piece of code, look at my post again, I edited it:

foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $file_path . $name);
}

Comment: Ok. Using your original code combined with the edit works great at uploading the selected files. Thanks for the code samples.

Comment: The correct answer would be: he referred to original name of the file on the client machine, but not to the file actually uploaded to the temporary directory.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the `$_FILES['files']['error']` array and check if the files are actually uploaded to the server:

```
$dest_dir = "../a/files/article-files/$year/$month";
foreach ($_FILES["files"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
  if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    // The temporary filename of the file stored on the server
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
    $name = basename($_FILES["files"]["name"][$key]);
    // Handle possible failure of the move_uploaded_file() function, too!
    if (! move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$dest_dir/$name")) {
      trigger_error("Failed to move $tmp_name to $dest_dir/$name",
        E_USER_WARNING);
    }
  } else {
    // Handle upload error
    trigger_error("Upload failed, key: $key, error: $error",
      E_USER_WARNING);
  }
}
```

The biggest issue with your code is that you are trying to move `$_FILES['files']['name']` instead of `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']`. The latter is a file name of temporary file uploaded into the [temporary directory](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir) used for storing files when doing file upload.

P.S.

Using relative paths is error-prone. Consider using absolute paths with the help of a constant containing path to the project root, e.g.:

*config.php*

```
<?php
define('MY_PROJECT_ROOT', __DIR__);
```

*upload.php*

```
<?php
require_once '../some/path/to/project/root/config.php';

$dest_dir = MY_PROJECT_ROOT . "/a/files/article-files/$year/$month";
```